# Does the /me/friends Facebook open graph API call ever get paginated?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination

I'm testing my app based on a friend list of about 350 people, and not seeing any pagination on `/me/friends/`.

What's unclear to me (by testing & documentation) is the following:

At how many friends do the `graph.facebook.com/me/friends` or `graph.facebook.com/ID/friends` open graph calls starts to paginate, if at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look at Graph API Explorer: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends) and scroll to the very bottom - you will there something like:

> "paging": {
>       "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=XXX"
>   }

which leads me to believe that default page size is 5000

you can set that limit explicitly if you want to: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%26limit%3D1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends&limit=1)

Comment: Makes sense. Generally speaking, I suppose the solution here is to continue making calls against the `response.paging.next` URL until I've hit a page with no more friend data. Thanks.

Comment: as today (tested 2.2) this seems not to be the case anymore, I did test that link and mine paginate every 25!! friends

Answer (score 6):

1. Set the limit yourself using limit=5000 for max limit. I.e so /me/friends?limit=5000
2. With the JavaScript SDK, two fields are returned, data and paging. Just hit the nextPage URL, and on the next result, there will be no more paging variable/next variable, indicating that you've hit the end.